# How to get list of elements of two sequences using Set.intersection

Tags: swift

I'm studying The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html

Is it possible to write a generic function to return the common elements of any two Sequences using Set.intersection()? I've written the following method (I'm a C# developer just learning, so please excuse bad Swift coding practices), but is it possible to do this without knowing the element type?

```
func getCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> Array<Any>
where T.Element: Equatable, T.Element == U.Element
{
if let lhsSet = lhs as? Set<String> {
    if let rhsSet = rhs as? Set<String> {
        return Array(lhsSet.intersection(rhsSet))
    }
} else if let lhsSet = lhs as? Set<Double> {
    if let rhsSet = rhs as? Set<Double> {
        return Array(lhsSet.intersection(rhsSet))
    }
} else if let lhsArray = lhs as? Array<String> {
    if let rhsArray = rhs as? Array<String> {
        let lhsSet = Set<String>(lhsArray)
        let rhsSet = Set<String>(rhsArray)
        return Array(lhsSet.intersection(rhsSet))
    }
}
return [T.Element]()
```

}

```
getCommonElements(["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"], ["FirstName", "LastName"])
let elementsSet1 = Set<Double>([1.2, 2.4, 3.6])
let elementsSet2 = Set<Double>([1.2, 3.6])
getCommonElements(elementsSet1, elementsSet2)
```

Comment: `common elements` means it conform to `Equatable `  or  `Comparable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can even just init a `Set` from the input anyway. Doesn't matter if it is `Set` or `Array` since your input is `Sequence` and `Set` can be init from `Sequence`. `where T.Element: Hashable, T.Element == U.Element` already guarantee the element types are the same and can be made as `Set`

```
func getCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Element] 
    where T.Element: Hashable, T.Element == U.Element
{
   return Array(Set<T.Element>(lhs).intersection(Set<U.Element>(rhs)))
}

print(getCommonElements(["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"], ["FirstName", "LastName"]))
let elementsSet1 = Set<Double>([1.2, 2.4, 3.6])
let elementsSet2 = Set<Double>([1.2, 3.6])
print(getCommonElements(elementsSet1, elementsSet2))
```

output:

```
["FirstName", "LastName"]
[1.2, 3.6]
```

Comment: Yes, but the return type should  be specific: `[T.Element]`, not `[Any]`.

Comment: Thank you!
Because of Swift's null handling and the constraints, there would be no benefit to coding the method like this versus your one line return statement with explicit casts, correct?

`func getCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Element]`
`where T.Element: Hashable, T.Element == U.Element`
`{`
`    if let lhsSet = lhs as? Set<T.Element> {`
`        if let rhsSet = rhs as? Set<U.Element> {`
`            return Array(lhsSet.intersection(rhsSet))`
`        }`
`    }`
`    return [T.Element]()`
`}`

Comment: Actually you cannot cast `Array` to `Set`, but you can init `Set` from `Array`. `Set<T.Element>(lhs)` is an initializer, i.e. constructor. It creates a new `Set` by taking the elements from the input sequence. `let lhsSet = lhs as? Set<T.Element>` is casting `T` to `Set`, which usually fails if `T` itself is not already a `Set`.  If you write `let array : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]; let set = array as? Set<Int>`, Xcode will alert you that `Cast from '[Int]' to unrelated type 'Set<Int>' always fails`

Comment: Got it, thank you for the clarification! So I can't assume that T.Element: Hashable means the collection can be cast or coerced to Set, but I can assume that the collection can be used to initialize a Set.